# How to hide/show adf component automatically

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi I want to hide an adf component automatically.I have a selectOneChoice that contain some number (from 1 to 12).
Example when I select 2, it show's two field automatically without clicking  any button..
i used this function to hide a declared componenet but just when i click a button..

```
  function enableField(actionEvent) {  

    var nameInputText = actionEvent.getSource().findComponent("soc1");  
    nameInputText.setProperty("visible", true);  
    actionEvent.cancel();  
  }
```

i set the componement "soc1" visible = true than through the javascript function i change it..

SO the probleme here is how to read the number from the selectonechoise and how to set the component visible directly without clicking any button.

Comment: Are you sure you want to hide it using javascript? It will be much easer from server side.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Rendered won't do what you want. You want to use Visible property instead. Rendered causes the actual markup for the component not to be rendered on the page, so a Partial Refresh will not cause it to appear. Rendered is reserved, usually, to hide items that are secure. We set rendered property to false on the item(s), but then refresh the *parent* containing component - usually a layout manager - then it works. So either refresh the layout manager that contains the item or use Visible. I demonstrated this exact use case last week in class and it works as described.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, you don't need javascript solution or any programming to achieve this.

You should set attributes `rendered`(this way component won't be rendered at the page at all) and `partialTriggers` that points to `selectOneChoice` component for components you want to show or hide. Also you have to set `autoSubmit="true"` for your `selectOneChoice` component.

```
<af:selectOneChoice id="soc1" autoSubmit="true" .../>
<af:panelGroupLayout id="plg1" partialTriggers="soc1">
  <af:outputText id="ot1" rendered="#{bindings.lov.inputValue le 1}"  inputValue="text1"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

*Note: its not working code, just a sample*

It will work following way, on valueChange event at selectOneChoice component value is submitted and partialRefresh fires for components that have it in `partialTriggers` specified. And `rendered` attribute will either render or remove component depending on it's EL expression. Components that should be managed wrapped into another component to make sure PPR reach it when they ain't rendered.